# Error trying to connect to mongolab from cdm: Error: 18 authentication fail

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mlab, database

[I'm getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUBQH.jpg) when I try to connect to my mongolab DB.

I saw some different topics talking about this issue, but solutions they gave was:

-Add mongoDB exception in my firewall. I done it without result

-Check if I was using the mongolab.com user and password instead of the user database. That's not the problem, even I created new users.

-Check if my version of mongoDB was older than the version used by mongolab (3.x). I also specified the auth system in the command to be sure.

I tried all those answers without success. I also checked the connection with the server, and it neither was the problem. I'm going crazy.

What could be the issue?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: You shouldn't need the --authenticationDatabase parameter. Are you certain the database name is correct? Feel free to contact support@mongolab.com if you still need assistance.

Comment: I added the authenticationDatabase parameter in order to fix the problem. Without this parameter it does not work anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was finally a network problem. I was lucky to discover it, cause I lost many hours.